# How to login to ASP website using python

Tags: python, authentication, asp-classic, urllib

I am trying to login to a ASP website using python. Here is what the login page looks like.

```
  <div class="menuitem">
      <form id="login" action="public.asp?sid=new" method="post">
          <ol>
              <li>
                  <label for="username">Username:</label>
                  <input name="username" id="username" type="text" />
              </li>
              <li>
                  <label for="password">Password:</label>
                  <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
              </li>
              <li>
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
              </li>
          </ol>
      </form>
  </div>
```

I tried this in my python code

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('http://www.battrick.org\public.asp', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://battrick.org/nl/playerdetails.asp?playerID=4456754')
print resp.read()
```

I am nost sure what URL to pass to the open() method.

Comment: Maybe use a forward slash in the URL instead of a backslash?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the [request](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) module. It is really simple in comparison with urllibs...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
session = requests.session()
payload = {'username': username, 'password': password}
data = session.post(url='http://www.battrick.org/public.asp?sid=new', data=payload)
print data, data.text
```